# how to set transparent layout in top of another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, transparent

i have layout and want to make transparent in this white space. i am use slidingupmenu library, this is my example layout :

[image: example]

and at this white space dont create transparent color, this is my xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#40ffffff" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/map_height" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space"
        android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alamat_wisata"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="Jl. Imam Bonjol"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/content_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jarak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alamat_wisata"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="25 Km"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/jarak"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_jarak" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Taman Krida Budaya"
        android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_center"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_1"
        app:cb_color="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        app:cb_pressed_ring_width="8dip" />

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/space"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_nearby"
        app:cb_color="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        app:cb_pressed_ring_width="8dip" />

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_rute"
        app:cb_color="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        app:cb_pressed_ring_width="8dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in the white space should be transparent and display a map.

Comment: which the white view ?

Comment: @Abdellah in the top of circle button, this is other fragment at top of map fragment.

Answer (score 0):

use @android:color/transparent in all component

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your color code.

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00